# Error 400 GET Bad Request with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, bad-request

I'm trying to do some scraping on a web application using Python to extract information from it, and it is protected by `HTTPBasicAuth`.

[image: Auth]

This is my code so far:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0' }

page = requests.get('https://10.0.0.1:999/app/info' , verify = False , auth = ('user' , 'pass'), headers = headers)

print (page.content.decode())
```

But I'm getting this answer from `print (page.content.decode())`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>400 - Bad Request</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>400 - Bad Request</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

What could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was using `HTTPBasicAuth`, and I had to use `HTTPDigestAuth`. Even though the website seemed to be using Basic Authentication, after an inspection of the traffic using Burp Proxy, I noticed it was using Digest Authentication.